# Return html tag by calling python function in django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Guys actually i am expecting the django view should return only the tag like

```
def load_tags():
   return httpresponse("<span>span tag</span>")

def home(request):
   return render(request, 'index.html',{"func":load_tags()})

html file

<h2>Calling python function {{ func }} </h2>
```

-In browser it displayed as

- **Calling python function <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">**

-But i am expecting as

- **Calling python function span tag**

Guys can you help me to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve your requirement like this...

#### views.py

```
def TagsView():
    html_h1 = "<h1>Hello django</h1>"
    html_italic = "<h4><i>Hello django</i></h4>"
    html_hr = "<hr>"
    my_code = "<code>print('Hello world')</code>"
    return html_h1,html_italic,html_hr,my_code

def DemoView(request):
    context = {"func":TagsView()}
    return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

#### HTML Code

```
{% block body %}
     {% autoescape off %}
          {% for i in func  %}
              {{i}} 
          {% endfor %}
     {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock body %}
```

#### Output

[image]